# Is it possible to make UISlider smaller?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uislider

I'm afraid I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't find an answer anywhere nor I can seem to figure it out on my own, so I'll ask here.

Is it possible to make an UISlider slightly smaller than the default one, just like the one seen in the "iPod" app on the iPhone? The height on Interface Builder seems to be frozen at 23 points.

How is it done on the iPod app? Does it use custom images?

Comment: Not Possible... u can't change the hight of UISlider

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had an idea on how to achieve this goal. But I couldn't try it myself. So I don't know if the slider works.

Use the transformation property of every `UIView` subclass:

```
yourslider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
```

But as I said, I don't know if the slider works anymore if you apply a transformation to it.

Comment: Let me now if the slider is still slideable. :-D

Comment: That won't work, as it also changes the transformation of the tracking dot, which is then going to be stretched into an ellipse.